# How can we load one entire react project in another react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, bundle, code-splitting, dynamic-import

If our 2 teams are developing 2 projects seperately and needs to integrate to the Parent App , how can we load or call the project . is it possible to share the session using MSAL for Authentication.

The solution for integration and deployment of 2 projects

Comment: you could use a webview, then in the routes, just have one route pointing to 1 app, and the other route to the other app.

Comment: in main parent app, have 2 routes, one for each app, and then just load the respective apps via those routes using webview

Comment: As a general rule, nesting React apps isn't a great idea (it's possible, but messy) however having multiple apps on a single page is perfectly fine. How interconnected are these two apps?